# Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/aether/spi/connector/Transfer$State

Tags: android, maven, pom.xml, building

Hii everyone I am trying to generate automated Maven build script for android project i'm using Maven 3.2.5 for generating build and i'm getting following issues while trying to generate script for sample helloworld project

```
   Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/eclipse/aether/spi/connector/Transfer$State
at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:608)
```

i'm using following script for building

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example.helloworld</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>

<properties>
    <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
        <version>21.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>21</platform>
                </sdk>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

tried changing and searched in google didn't find solution please help me

Answer (score 17):

It seems that there is a compatibility issues between *android-maven-plugin* and the *maven* release 3.2.5 and later.

For me it works on a 3.2.3 and fails with **NoClassDefFoundError** exception when I use 3.2.5 and 3.3.1

Try to download an older maven version from the archives at 
http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.3/

---

**Edit**

This issue is fixed in later versions(testet with 4.1.1) of the *android-maven-plugin*. The plugin has moved to github, and is relocated to a new groupId.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
  </plugin>
```

New project location:
https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

There is some compatibility problem for maven 3.2 & 3.3.  Try this:

```
brew install homebrew/versions/maven31
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/maven31/3.1.1 /usr/local/Cellar/maven/
brew switch maven 3.1.1
```